# Removing Repository In Git Bash Without Deleting The Folder

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm very new to git and am using git bash for about 3 days now. When following a tutorial I accidently wrote `git init` in the wrong folder, that of my user in the computer.  Sadly this means that I can't just delete the folder as it will cause me problems.

Looking online I found `git rm -r --cached FolderName`
Which didn't work, resulting in:
"*fatal pathspec 'FolderName' did not match any files*"

All in all, I hope to change the repository from this random important folder to a folder much further down the folder path, without deleting the current folder the repository is in currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git stores its repository data in a hidden `.git` folder. If you therefore delete said directory via a simple `rm -rf .git` you will remove the repository from your current directory. Alternatively you could move the `.git` folder with a `mv .git <your desired location here>`. Both would not harm your existing folder structure.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. It tool longer than I thought it would, so for a second it seemed to have crashed